# BI: Dedicated date tables for each date column in a related dimension table

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, business-intelligence, ssas-tabular

I am using Power BI Dataset (SSAS) / DAX but I think this is a general BI question.  I have a store table with two separate date columns.  I want to use both date columns for filtering over different time ranges.

For example, my main dimension table is 'Store'.

Store has [Open Date] and [Close Date] columns where each store in the list has its own open and close dates.  I want to connect 'Store' to date tables so that I can filter the list over different date ranges; each date table has columns that provide different date formatting (Q#, MM-YYYY, etc.).

I want to be able to filter Store in a way where I could return, as an example, all of the stores with an [Open Date] in Q1 2020 and a [Close Date] in 12-2022.

Is the best practice here to have two separate copies of the date table in the model with 'Store'[Open Date] and 'Store'[Close Date]' each having a relationship to their own unique table so each can be filtered independently?

P.S. my actual problem involves more than two date columns, so trying to determine whether each date column having its own date table is overkill.  I have used inactive relationships between different date fields to a single date table, but then that involves accessing the filtered conditions through measures, which adds complexity and reduces flexibility.

Comment: While a pair of tables can only have one *active* relationship at a time, it can have multiple inactive relationships. You just need to use USERELATIONSHIP() in the CALCULATE function to specify the pair of related fields.

Comment: @Pieter that makes sense, and I have used that before, but that means all filtering and visualization needs to be done through measures - trying to have a way to do without needing to create a measure.  Single table connected by inactive relationships complicates the ability to use different slicers so that end users can select the date ranges they need for each date to get to the accurate set of stores. I think the answer is if there is a need to slice different date fields by different distinct date ranges, then there needs to be different date tables to filter, but I'm hoping to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this is a good example of why you want only one calendar table...
Say I create a simple measure, like
Total Sales Dollars := SUMX('SalesFact',[Quantity] * RELATED('DimProduct'[UnitPrice]))

and then I want to compare to the previous year. If I have the explicit measure, it's a piece of cake:
`CALCULATE( [Total Sales Dollars], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('DimDate'[Date]))`  ... but it only works if you have the correct date dimension table in your SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR() function. If you don't, you get an unfiltered total with the same value for every time period in your visual.

Say you have your measure, and you drop it into the Values section of a matrix visualization. If you have multiple calendar tables, which one do you use when? if you choose the wrong one, you'll get the standard list of dates/time units on one axis, but all the values will be the same, because the filtering happens through the relationship.

You can have multiple calendar tables in your model, but it gets confusing. If you use USERELATIONSHIP(), you can have ONE calendar table and do running sums etc based on ShipDate, OrderDate, ManufactureDate etc (whatever date columns you have in your fact table) and you don't have to change your model.
I would swear Adam Saxton (from GuyInACube) did a video on Calendar tables and how PowerBI deals with a data model where no table is marked as a date/calendar table, because I'd swear it's where I learned it. Check the GuyInACube YouTube channel - there are several on dates.

Comment: points well taken; there is definitely need for single table w/ inactive relationships tied to the different dates w/ measures built on top so there is way to access all events occurring on single timeline (e.g. count of store openings/closings in FY23). But again, that requires the end user to know DAX if they are doing their own ad hoc analysis. So it seems like we're left with only technical users building reports - either know the data model to avoid confusion of multiple date tables, or know how to write DAX and remove filters, etc.  Definitely a lot of good content from Cube Guys

Comment: I'm thinking it will be valuable to have both a single default date table w/ inactive relationships for building measures that share dates.  And then have separate date field specific date tables named for the date they are associated with so it is easy to filter on the fly without needing to write a measure.

Comment: On the last comment, how do you mean? Could you give an example? "without needing to write a measure"? While you can create implicit measures, they're not very flexible, and you can't reuse anything. (Like create a measure, then create a second measure using the first, but date-shifting it, say back 3 months.)

Comment: Example: user wants to see list of 'Stores' where [Open Date] is in "Q1 2020" AND [Close Date] is in "12-2022"-needs to meet those specific date conditions. In Power BI, user could drag these fields to a table and then filter on the two date columns. That would be "without a measure" - direct filtering - easy. However, [Open Date] and [Close Date] are mm/dd/yyyy format; one benefit of a date table is that different date formats can be accessed through date field relationship. If user wants to display as "Q1 2020" and "12-2022" instead of mm/dd/yyyy, then distinct date tables are needed.